# closing mdi child form causes System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi

i created a mdi database application. One child form has a datagridview. when clicking on a button on that form a new form opens with a pdfviewer(AxAcroPDF1) on it. This form shows a pdf document stored in the sql server database.

closing this form is done by Me.Close(). It closes it, but when i do it several times, opening that form and closing it, then at one point i get a 
System.ObjectDisposedException which says Cannot access a disposed object and it isn't caught either in the try catch block.

It also says The application is in break mode. Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads where executing external code(typically system or framwork code)

Never experienced this kind of problem before.

Here is the code to launch the form with the pdf viewer

```
Private Sub btnShowDocument_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowDocument.Click
    frmDocument = New frmShowDocumentatie

    rowIndex = dgvData.CurrentRow.Index

    FileName = dgvData.Item(6, rowIndex).Value


        If FileName = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Can't open documentation" & vbNewLine & "File doesn't exist", "Database Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Else
             frmDocument.Show()

        End If      

End Sub
```

And here's the form that opens up then

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frmShowDocumentatie


'local variables to get passed the public shared values from
'curent selected row index and document name in datagridview
Private iRow As Integer
Private fName As String

Private Sub frmShowDocumentatie_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'sets the mdi parent
    MdiParent = MDIParent1
    'sets the text of the form to the filename of pdf bestand
    Me.Text = "Document: " & getFilename()

    'loads the pdf bestand, need the filepath which is provided by getfilepath function
    AxAcroPDF1.src = GetFilePath()

    'gets the values from the selected row index and corrsponding filename
    iRow = frmDataView.rowIndex
    fName = frmDataView.FileName

    tsmiDocument.Text = "Document: " & getFilename()

End Sub

'function for getting the filename of selected pdf file in datagridview
Public Function getFilename() As String
    fName = frmDataView.FileName
    getFilename = fName
End Function

'gets the file path of selected pdf bestand
Function GetFilePath() As String
    'Dim i As Integer = frmVerledenOverzicht.dgvData.CurrentRow.Index
    'Dim filename As String = frmVerledenOverzicht.dgvData.Item(6, i).Value

    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim buffer As Byte()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AndriesKamminga;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select  Bestand From dbo.PaVerledenOverzicht WHERE Documentatie =" & "'" & getFilename() & "';", conn)
            buffer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
    sFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
    System.IO.File.Move(sFilePath, System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf"))
    sFilePath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf")
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sFilePath, buffer)

    'returns the file path needed for AxAcroPDF1
    GetFilePath = sFilePath

End Function

Private Sub tsmiSluiten_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsmiSluiten.Click
    Try
         Me.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Database Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

anyone knows what's causing this exception and why is the program crashing instead of being caught in the try catch block
Am using visual studio community edition 2017

Comment: System.ObjectDisposedException occurred
  HResult=0x80131622
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
  Source=System.Drawing

Comment: StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Icon.get_Handle()
   at System.Drawing.Icon.get_Size()
   at System.Drawing.Icon.BmpFrame()
   at System.Drawing.Icon.ToBitmap()
   at System.Windows.Forms.MdiControlStrip.GetTargetWindowIcon()
   at System.Windows.Forms.MdiControlStrip..ctor(IWin32Window target)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateMdiControlStrip(Boolean maximized)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateToolStrip()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnMdiChildActivate(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActivateMdiChildInternal(Form form)

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmMdiActivate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DefMDIChildProc(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.Form.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmSetFocus(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WmSetFocus(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: The call stack seems to suggest that it's something to do with a `ToolStrip`.  Are you merging a `ToolStrip` and/or `MenuStrip` or using a `MenuStrip` with an MDI list item on it?

Comment: i did put a menu strip on the mdi child form, which is shown then on the parent form. since the menustrip on the child form is only visible on the parent form i pulled the pdfviewer(AxAcroPDF1) on the child form up till over the menustrip of the child form to give it more space and the MenuStrip will still be shown then on the parent form. so maybe its caused by the pdfviewer covering the menustrip?

Comment: did move the pdfviewer down, but still the same problem. I copied the code from a previous app i made, and didn't have that problem there. So the code is the same. The only difference is, the mdi application that doesn't crash hasn't got a MDI Window List Menu, the one that causes the problem has

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new test project and trying to do the minimum you can to reproduce the issue. If you can provide us with the steps required then we can investigate and it may end up being a .NET or VS bug. If we can't reproduce the issue then it may be something corrupt on your system and if you can't reproduce the issue then it may be something corrupt in your project.

Comment: this is what shown when i click the details of the exception   $exception Unable to evaluate the expression. i did remove the pdfviewer(AxAcroPDF1) from the child form, opened and closed it many times and the exception doesn't occur. But as soon as i put the pdfviewer back on, in the middle of the child form, so it doesn't touch or merge with the menubar, the exception occurs again. it's weird since the code is the same in a similar project where it doesn't crash. will make a new project to see if it crashes there

Comment: Maybe you could handle the `FormClosing` event and clean up the viewer as much as possible before the form is actually disposed.

Comment: i tried AxAcroPDF1.src = "Nothing.pdf" and AxAcroPDF1.Dispose() before closing the form, but the exception still occurs . The exception can happen at the 10 the time of closing the form or in the beginning, it's really random. i maximized and minimized the form before closing but that doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: I added a MDI Window List Menu to the application that is not crashing and now it's crashing with the same exception as well. it seems that the MDI Window List Menu and the pdfviewer or their interaction is causing the problem, is there any solution for that except removing it? – Shimrod